# How secure is storing a file on iPhone and Windows Phone 7?

Tags: ios, security, windows-phone-7

How secure it is to store a file on windows phone 7 and iPhone?

As in Android, we have some file browser utility which shows all the files and folders stored on the sdcard of the device which allows user to copy, move, delete, and do other short of activities.

In case of Windows Phone 7 and iPhone, it seems there is no such file browser utility and I guess the storage architecture of these systems are different from Android which does not allows file browsing.

In my case for Android, I would encrypt the file and store it to make it more secure. I may also play with file and folder attributes.

For the case of iPhone and Windows Phone 7, do I need to encrypt the file and store it?

OR

I can put file without applying encryption assuming that no other application will be able to access that file nor the user will be able to do the same?

What are the other alternates for securing a file on these devices?

Thank you

Comment: For iOS, on a jailbroken device, user can do anything. I am not sure whether encryption can do anything to protect your file against the determined hacker, though.

Comment: not assuming jailbroken and unlocked devices.

Comment: If you want useful answers you should (1) split this into one question each for iOS and Windows Phone and (2) be specific in your requirements (what sort of actions you want to prevent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows Phone all data and applications are sandboxed so they cannot access each other or share/access each others data.

Security is obviously a relative thing. If someone is persistent enough they will be able to get the files created by your app off of the device but it is not a simple task for most people.

If you really don't want anyone else to be able to read your files then you will need to store them in an encrypted format that uses encryption keys which are not stored in code or on the device.

**Updated**
If you want to safely encrypt data on the device then you need to remember that if someone can get access to the files you're saving they can also get to your code, decompile it, read it and run it themselves.
The only real way round this is to have the user enter a user name and password each time you run the app (important: **you MUST NOT SAVE THIS PASSWORD**). These credentials are then used to access an external resource (web server) which uses those credentials to return a key (which again you **MUST NOT SAVE**)  which you use for encryption/decryption.

Security is a compromise and you need to weigh up whether this overhead is worth it and necessary for the security of the data you're trying to protect.

Comment: could you please explain little bit more about "uses encryption keys which are not stored in code or on the device"? It will be really helpful to me.

Answer (score 1):

Who are you trying to hide the file from? The user of the phone?

If so, especially on Android, there will always be a way for the user to access the file.

If you want to protect the contents of a file, don't rely on the operating system hiding it. That's a [bad idea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity).

All of the operating systems you've listed offer encryption as part of their API. Look up the details.

Comment: trying to hide file from user and other apps

Comment: Encrypt it properly then, would be my advice. Don't rely on it just being hidden by the OS - it won't do a very good job versus a determined user.

Answer (score 0):

On the iPhone you can use a utility such as Senuti or Phonedisk to browse the file system, many even allow you to mount the phone as a disk and browse that way. Many iOS apps store their files in the applicationsupport or documents directory, which are not protected in any way.

http://www.macroplant.com/phonedisk/

The only alternative is to encrypt the file if you don't want the user to view it. Look into the CommonCrypto framework